# Loop to get time series plots with plotly library

Tags: r, function, loops, plot, plotly

I want to use the "plotly" library in order to get several time series plots for every numeric variable in a `data.frame`. I don't know why, but all plots refer to last one.

Here is what I have tried:

```
install.packages("plotly", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
library("plotly")
dfdata <- apply(economics[,2:6], 2, scale)
df1 <- data.frame(dfdata, economics$date)

plotting <- function(data) {
  a <- list()
  for (i in 1:5) { 
    nam <- paste("p", i, sep = "")
    nam <- plot_ly(data, x = economics.date, y = data[,i])
    a[[i]] <- nam
  }
  return(a)
}

b <- plotting(df1)
b
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason all plots refer to the last variable is that the `plot_ly` function does not evaluate during the loop, but instead just keeps a reference to the data. This can be changed by using the `evaluate` parameter in the `plot_ly` function.

Modify your function code like this and each of the entries in the list returned by `plotting` are now different.

```
plotting <- function(data) {
    a <- list()
    for (i in 1:5) { 
        nam <- paste("p", i, sep = "")
        nam <- plot_ly(data, x = economics.date, y = data[,i], evaluate = TRUE)
        a[[i]] <- nam
    }
    return(a)
}
```

EDIT:
This example uses `plotly` 3.x.x. If you use `plotly` 4.x.x or above, this code may not work as is. See here for more details: https://www.r-bloggers.com/upgrading-to-plotly-4-0-and-above/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a single plot for each variable, you can just do something like:

```
b <- lapply(setdiff(names(df1), "economics.date"), function(x) {
  plot_ly(df1, x = df1[["economics.date"]], y = df1[[x]])
})

b
```

The `setdiff(names(df1), "economics.date")` gives us a vector of each of the other columns, which we can refer to in the `lapply` statement.

Comment: Ah, Dear Ananda, why do I have a feeling that this was for the "Weed Eater"? ... :)

Comment: @BhargavRao, because it was..... But I got it elsewhere :-) Nice hat collectioncollection you've got there by the way!!!

Comment: @BhargavRao, I got it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34456039/1270695) if I'm not mistaken. And, in case you want to know what you might want to call yourself for the rest of today, [check this out](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142420/a-name-for-hat-collectors) :-)

Comment: Thanks. ... Why did you slack on the way? You were 2nd on the leaderboard once :)

Comment: @BhargavRao, My work requires travel from time to time, and this was one of those periods. Only so much that can be answered on a phone....

Comment: Nice. 29 hats is a great achievement also! Congrats. Do ping me next time (here or in chat) if you are searching for "hats". I'll be glad to join you :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99580/discussion-between-ananda-mahto-and-bhargav-rao).